# static variable storage

Tags: c

In C, where is static variable stored in memory? Suppose there are two static variables, one local to a function and the other global. How is this entry maintained in symbol table? Please explain.

Comment: What do you mean by "static variable"? Static storage duration? Or internal linkage?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In *C*, they can be stored wherever the implementation sees fit. The C standard does not dictate how the implementation does things, only how it *behaves.*

Typically, all static storage duration variables (statics within a function and all variables outside a function) will be stored in the same region, regardless of whether they at at file level or within a function.

That bit in parentheses above is important. Outside of a function, `static` doesn't decide the storage duration of a variable like it does within a function. It decides whether the variable is visible outside of the current translation unit. *All* variables outside of functions are static storage duration.

And, regarding the symbol table, that's a construct that exists only during the build process. Once an executable is generated, there are no symbols (debugging information excluded of course, but that has nothing to do with the execution of code). All references to variables at that point will almost certainly be hard-coded addresses or offsets.

In other words, it's the compiler that figures out which variable you're referring to with a name.

---

You can see an example here as to how the variables are stored. Consider the following little C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int var1;
static int var2;
int main (void) {
    int var3;
    static int var4;

    var1 = 111;
    var2 = 222;
    var3 = 333;
    var4 = 444;

    return 0;
}
```

This generates the following assembly:

```
.file             "qq.c"
.comm             var1,4,4
.local            var2
.comm             var2,4,4
.text
.globl            main
.type             main, @function
main:
    pushl         %ebp
    movl          %esp, %ebp
    subl          $16, %esp
    movl          $111, var1
    movl          $222, var2
    movl          $333, -4(%ebp)
    movl          $444, var4.1705
    movl          $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
.size             main, .-main
.local            var4.1705
.comm             var4.1705,4,4
.ident            "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3"
.section          .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

And you can see that `var1`, `var2` and `var4` (the static storage duration ones) all have a `.comm` line to mark them as common entries, subject to consolidation by the linker.

In addition, `var2`, `var3` and `var4` (the ones that are invisible outside the current transdlation unit) all have a `.local` line, so that the linker won't use them for satisfying unresolved externals in other object file.

And, by examining the output of `ld --verbose` while linking a file, you can see that all common entries end up in the `.bss` area:

```
  .bss            :
  {
   *(.dynbss)
   *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
   *(COMMON)
   : : :
  }
```

Comment: @prp, `gcc -S` will output the assembly code to standard out.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to generalize to every compiler, but this is how it's most often done.

There will be a block of memory set aside by the linker for variables which are initialized at load time but modifiable at run time. All static variables will be placed in this block no matter if they are local or global.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following source:

```
static int a_static_var = 5;

void foo(void)
{
    static int a_static_var = 6;

    return;
}
```

Visual Studio compiles the variable as follows (at lest in this instance - details will vary from compiler to compiler and depend on options):

```
_DATA   SEGMENT
_a_static_var DD 05H
?a_static_var@?1??foo@@9@9 DD 06H           ; `foo'::`2'::a_static_var
_DATA   ENDS
```

So both static variables end up in the data segment - the static that's scoped to a function has it's name mangled in such a way that it will not 'match up' with a similar variable ion a different function or source file.

Compiler implementations are free to handle this is whatever manner, but the general idea will usually be similar.